# SQL=0104N: Обнаружен неправильный элемент

Tags: db2, ibm, база-данных

Использую DB2 Express-c v10.1. Помогите разобраться с написанием запроса. Сам запрос:

```
db2 create table plane (id_plane SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, type char(20) primary key not null, width SMALLINT not null)
```

После выполнения запроса появляется сообщение:

> `SQL=0104N Обнаружен неправильный элемент "id_plane SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREM" после текста "create table plane (". Список возможных правильных элементов: "<col_name>". SQLSTATE=42601`

Заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в кавычки необязательно. как то так, должно работать)

```
create table plane (
id_plane INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY primary key, type varchar(20),
width integer);

INSERT INTO plane(type) VALUES ('type1');
INSERT INTO plane(type) VALUES ('type33');
INSERT INTO plane(type) VALUES ('type222');
SELECT * FROM plane;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db2 create table plane ("id_plane" SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, type char(20) primary key not null, width SMALLINT not null)
```

Answer (score 0):

Первый раз вижу чтобы <COLUMN name> брали в кавычки.
К сожалению ошибка аналогична. Я как понял в DB2 не используется AUTO_increment.Решение нашлось:
DB2 обеспечивает поддержку автоматической генерации ID столбцов с помощью GENERATE и IDENTITY.
Will need to be converted to the following statement in DB2:

```
CREATE TABLE records 
(id INTEGER GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),...
```

Comment: как то так я и написал)))

Comment: да я уже увидел:) спасибо за оперативность!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста)

Comment: извиняюсь за нозойливость, а не могли бы вы посмотреть еще такой вопрос: DB2: Как вывести в нормализованной таблице данные из других таблиц?